# Query GPT4All local model with Langchain and many .txt files - KeyError: 'input_variables'

Tags: python, neo4j, langchain

`python 3.8, Windows 10, neo4j==5.14.1, langchain==0.0.336`

I'm attempting to utilize a local Langchain model (GPT4All) to assist me in converting a corpus of loaded `.txt` files into a `neo4j` data structure through querying. I have provided a minimal reproducible example code below, along with the references to the article/repo that I'm attempting to emulate. I have also provided a "context" that should be included in the query, along with all the `Document` objects. I'm still learning how to use `Langchain` so I really don't know what I'm doing yet, but the current traceback I'm getting looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\neo4jmain.py", line xx, in <module>
    prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\load\serializable.py", line 97, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 339, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 1102, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\langchain\schema\prompt_template.py", line 76, in validate_variable_names
    if "stop" in values["input_variables"]:
KeyError: 'input_variables'
```

As you'll see, I'm literally not defining `input_variables` anywhere, so I assume this is a default behaviour of Langchain, but again, not sure. I was also getting an error:

```
LLaMA ERROR: The prompt is 5161 tokens and the context window is 2048!
ERROR: The prompt size exceeds the context window size and cannot be processed.
```

...which is clearly a result of the query string itself being too big. I want to be able to query my documents for the answer, while providing the model with the Documents to reference. How can I do this? The Langchain documentation is not great for noobies in this space, it's all over the place and lacks MANY, SIMPLE use cases for noobies so I'm asking it here.

````
# https://medium.com/neo4j/enhanced-qa-integrating-unstructured-and-graph-knowledge-using-neo4j-and-langchain-6abf6fc24c27
# https://github.com/sauravjoshi23/ai/blob/main/retrieval%20augmented%20generation/integrated-qa-neo4j-langchain.ipynb

# Script to convert a corpus of many text files into a neo4j graph

# Imports
import os
from langchain.document_loaders import TextLoader
from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
from langchain.llms.gpt4all import GPT4All
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Load tokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")

def bert_len(text):
    """Return the length of a text in BERT tokens."""
    tokens = tokenizer.encode(text)
    return len(tokens)

def get_files(path: str) -> list:
    """Return a list of all files in a directory, recursively."""
    files = []
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        file_path = os.path.join(path, file)
        if os.path.isdir(file_path):
            files.extend(get_files(file_path))
        else:
            files.append(file_path)
    return files

# Get the text files
all_txt_files = get_files('data')
raw_txt_files = []
for current_file in all_txt_files:
    raw_txt_files.extend(TextLoader(current_file, encoding='utf-8').load())

# Create a text splitter object that will help us split the text into chunks
text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(
    chunk_size = 1024, # 200,
    chunk_overlap = 128, # 20
    length_function = bert_len,
    separators=['\n\n', '\n', ' ', ''],
)

# Split the text into "documents"
documents = text_splitter.create_documents([raw_txt_files[0].page_content])

# Utilizing these Document objects, we want to query the GPT4All model to help us create
# a JSON object that contains the ontology of terms mentioned in the given context,
# while mitigating "max_tokens" error.
# Create a PromptTemplate object that will help us create the prompt for GPT4All(?)
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(
    template = """
    You are a network graph maker who extracts terms and their relations from a given context.
    You are provided with a context chunk (delimited by ```). Your task is to extract the ontology
    of terms mentioned in the given context. These terms should represent the key concepts as per the context.
    
    Thought 1: While traversing through each sentence, Think about the key terms mentioned in it.
        Terms may include object, entity, location, organization, person,
        condition, acronym, documents, service, concept, etc.
        Terms should be as atomistic as possible
    
    Thought 2: Think about how these terms can have one on one relation with other terms.
        Terms that are mentioned in the same sentence or the same paragraph are typically related to each other.
        Terms can be related to many other terms
        
    Thought 3: Find out the relation between each such related pair of terms.

    Format your output as a list of json. Each element of the list contains
    a pair of terms and the relation between them, like the following:
    [Dict("node_1": "A concept from extracted ontology",
            "node_2": "A related concept from extracted ontology",
            "edge": "relationship between the two concepts, node_1 and node_2 in one or two sentences",
        ),
    Dict("node_1": "A concept from extracted ontology",
        "node_2": "A related concept from extracted ontology",
        "edge": "relationship between the two concepts, node_1 and node_2 in one or two sentences",
    ),
    Dict(...)]
    Context Documents: {documents}
    """,
    variables = {
        "documents": documents,
    }
)

# Create a GPT4All object that will help us query the GPT4All model
llm = GPT4All(
    model=r"C:\Users\chalu\AppData\Local\nomic.ai\GPT4All\gpt4all-falcon-q4_0.gguf",
    n_threads=3,
    max_tokens=5162, # <-- attempt to mitigate "max_tokens" error
    verbose=True,
)

# Get the response from GPT-4-All
response = llm(prompt_template)
print(response)
````

Comment: You are actually asking 2 completely separate questions. You should move the second question out into a new question.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to the `KeyError: 'input_variables'` error: as [documented](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/model_io/prompts/prompt_templates/), the `PromptTemplate` parameter for input variables is named `input_variables`. So you need to change your `variables` parameter name to `input_variables`.

*And, yes, the error message should be much better worded.*

Comment: The documentation is all over the place, hard to follow. BUT, I changed that line to `input_variables=["documents"]`, and now get the error `ValueError: Argument `prompt` is expected to be a string. Instead found <class 'langchain.prompts.prompt.PromptTemplate'>. If you want to run the 
LLM on multiple prompts, use `generate` instead.` How do I fix that now? GPT4All doesn't have a generate method??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your text is formatted properly. I solved this issue by using more curly braces.

i.e. `prompt = """If the other prompt contains: "dont do this {task}" then do {other task}"""` IS NO GOOD
`prompt = """If the other prompt contains: "dont do this {{task}}" then do {other task}"""` IS FINE PROBABLY